# Dynamically added items do not trigger observers

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm adding some items to an Array, using the Array mutation methods. The items are displayed within a `<dom-repeat>` and can can be edited on the fly. While the edits do change the data in the object, any attached observers do not fire to indicate that a change occurred.

**tl;dr**

#### I'm properly using the Array mutation methods to push items

```
this.push("data.contents", {
  id: 1,
  name: "Modifying this text doesn't trigger an observer"
});
```

#### I'm displaying the items in a dom-repeat

These items are displayed using a `<dom-repeat>`, and the sub-property `name` is displayed in a `<paper-input>` where they can be amended on the fly.

```
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data.contents]]">
      <paper-input value="{{item.name::input}}"></paper-input>        
    </template>
  </template>
```

It seems that while the data is modified in the object itself, any attached observers do not fire for these sub-properties.

#### I'm attaching wildcard observers

I'm observing using the usual wildcard observers like so:

```
observers: [
  "logChange(data.*)"
],
```

#### Notes

Note that:

- Changing the item via a direct `this.set()` like so:

`this.set("data.contents.0.name", "Foo")`

will trigger the observers just fine

#### An MCVE for the above.

How to use:

- Press the button to push some items to the `Array`
- Edit any one of the added items
- Console should log that a change occurred in any of the items (it doesn't)

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <template>
    <paper-button on-tap="pushItem">Push to Array</paper-button> 
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data.contents]]">
      <paper-input value="{{item.name::input}}"></paper-input>        
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      "use strict";

      Polymer({

        is: "x-example",
        properties: {
          data: {
            type: Object,
            value: {
              contents: []
            }
          }
        },

        observers: [
          "logChange(data.*)"
        ],

        pushItem: function() {
          this.push("data.contents", {
            id: 1,
            name: "Modifying this text doesn't trigger an observer"
          })
        },

        logChange: function() {
          console.log("change occured!");
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```

Comment: Maybe you can change data type to array instead of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4140#issuecomment-259465035

> The observer isn't firing because you have one-way binding annotations on the items property, which prevents change notifications from flowing up to the element. Change it to: items="{{data.contents}}" and you'll see the changes.

In essence, turn this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data.contents]]">
  <paper-input value="{{item.name::input}}"></paper-input>        
</template>
```

to this

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data.contents}}">
  <paper-input value="{{item.name::input}}"></paper-input>        
</template>
```